# can i share Facebook user.name and user.id with multiple views

Tags: ios, facebook, protocols

i have worked on this project for a couple of months and i have only been programming for about a year so im not to smart on this subject so please be patient, i have create a login with Facebook and once i fetch the user info i have created a method to parse the info to the login view [image]

and i place this method in the [image]

and this method pushes to the loginViewController once it has received the info, im try to pass the same info to the settingViewController to show the name and the pic which is user.name and user.id and i did the same steps and use the same protocols and it doesnt work now my question is, because im useing the info in the loginViewController i cant place or use them in the settingViewController because im using the info already. could you please help me out with this i have only just in the last month sort of rapped my head around using protocols.

Comment: Did you try adding the data you get back from facebook to a custom class then passing the data using the prepareForSegue: method?

Comment: that sounds like a crazy great idea please help me send me in the right direction on how to do that a link to a tutorial maybe please

Answer (score 0):

Store all your fetched data in an custom class and pass the object to your destination view controller using

```
(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

using something like this here UBO is my Custom class  and user is facebook user object... that object contains id, image and email address..

UBO  = [[UserBusinessObject alloc]init];

UBO.userid=user.id;

NSLog(@"%@",UBO.userid);

UBO.email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];

NSLog(@"%@",UBO.email);

NSString *imageUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal",UBO.userid];

NSLog(@"%@image returning",imageUrl);

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
                 //NSLog(@"image data %@",imageData);
                  UBO.profilePic=imageData;

Comment: how to store the info in custom class i need tutorial or something to show me the process

Comment: this is tutorial for creating Custom classes  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQ_w0O2-Zuw

Comment: i understand the custom class and how to create one but witht the facebook login which is in my LoginViewController once i press the login button it has a method that then fetches the data and places it so how do i create a custom class that holds the data

Comment: create an object using that custom class. for example your custom class is FacebookDataClass and its instace variables are id,name,image.... then create a custom class object using FacebookDataClass * myobject =[[FacebookDataClass alloc]init];  then store your fetched values in the custom class using myobject.id = fetchedid;  myobject.name = fetchedname;  myobject.image = fetchedimage..... now you send the myobject to the destination view controller usinf prepare for seque

Comment: i have edited the above answer please have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set an identifier for the `segue`:

[image]

and set **profilePicture** (your case) **as a public property** in the 2nd view controller.

Then in your 1st view controller, simply use `prepareForSegue:` to pass your `profilePicture property`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondVCSegue"]) {

        SecondViewController *secondVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        secondVC.profilePicture = profilePicture;
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

have you identified the view controller in your storyboard ?

[image]

Comment: ok i understand but im using a slide menu so when i click on the settings cell in the slide menu the segue that is connected or the transition which happens thats where i should be doing the applying info

Comment: oh and im not using a segue though, but because im using navController does that mean i can use prepareForSegue in any transition period

Comment: i dont fully understand when and where i can use prepareForSegue

Comment: you could implement it in your view controller, it's a method from `UIViewController` cf: [apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue:sender:)

Comment: which view LoginView, ProfileView,

Comment: In your main view controller, the view controller from which you want to display the second view controller.

Comment: that means i have to pass the facebook data that is retrieved when the facebook login button is pressed which is in the LoginView right and pass it to the mainView

Comment: i understand the custom class and how to create one but witht the facebook login which is in my LoginViewController once i press the login button it has a method that then fetches the data and places it so how do i create a custom class that holds the data